# How to hide "previous" button in pagination when on the first page?

Tags: html, css, bigcartel

I'm simply looking to hide the "previous" button when you're on, let's say, page 1 of page 10. Because why need the "previous" button there if you can't go back more? Also, I would like to hide the "next" button when you're on the last page (page 10 of page 1), because again, you can't go further, so why have a "next" button on the last page?

**I'm using BigCartel, and the variables for the code look like this:**

```
{% if paginate.previous.is_link or paginate.next.is_link %}
{{ paginate | default_pagination }}
{% endif %}
% else %}
<p class="alert-noproducts">No products found.</p>
{% endif %}
```

**The CSS looks like this:**

```
#pagination .disabled,
#pagination .next,
#pagination .previous {
display: inline;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this:

```
#pagination .previous.disabled { display:none; }
```

you will also want to add this for when you're on the last page:

```
#pagination .next.disabled { display:none; }
```

---

You can combine them as well:

```
#pagination .previous.disabled, #pagination .next.disabled { display:none; }
```